# Monte Carlo method for solving integrals

Tags: integration, monte-carlo, simulation

My professor gives us an intro to how to evaluate integration using Monte Carlo method.
But I tried to search about it and never find the algorithm he used.

**Any help how can I find an explanation of this approach**
[image]

Comment: You could start with the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration

Comment: Certainly the term "Monte Carlo" is used for a lot of different algorithms, conveying that random sampling is used to estimate a value (the name being famous for [a casino in Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_Casino)).  Here the idea is to estimate the area under a curve as a fraction of a rectangular area that encloses it.  Many references can be found for this idea.  What exactly would you like to know?

Comment: I did but didn't find the above method @EthanBolker

Comment: @hardmath I know that there are many algorithms and I found them when I searched but I looking for a specific method that described in the above pic . I really can't find anything about it

Comment: It is not the best explanation, but there are some obvious ideas here to understand if you read it sympathetically.  Apparently $F$ is the same function as $f$ in the definite integral $\int_a^b f(x)\;dx$.  The rectangular box $ (a,b) \times (0,F_{\max})$ should be assumed to enclose the area of integration, and the sample of "N runs" gives us a fraction $K/N$ of that rectangular area that falls under the curve.  Is the idea clear?

Comment: @hardmath Yea that's what it means

Comment: So, if you understand the idea, what question would you like to ask?  It is a very brief sketch of the algorithm, and could stand clarification in a few places, but you've not said where you found this "picture" so possibly there is some context there you should consider.  Also there are a number of previous Questions on this site about "Monte Carlo integration", and you should look at some of these under the Related heading to the right of your post (at least on the desktop version of this page).

Comment: Part of why you probably haven't been able to find it is because for integrating *functions* (as opposed to finding the area inside the region defined by some inequality) this is a bad Monte Carlo procedure. That is because its variance is unnecessarily high. If you instead take the average of $f(U_x)$ and do not draw from $U_y$ at all, and then multiply that by $b-a$ (and not by $f_{max}$), then the result has a lower variance. The resulting procedure does the same number of evaluations of $f$ and generates half as many random numbers as in your procedure.

Comment: @Ian:  But that would be less a Monte Carlo method and more of a Riemann sum/trapezoid integration (with random partition of $(a,b)$ ).

Comment: @hardmath It is definitely still a Monte Carlo method. It's not a random partition, which would use uneven weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a script that approximated an integral using the Monte Carlo method for a first year university MatLab project. The concept is quite simple when considered graphically.

Imagine that there is a graph $y=f(x)$, within the domain $[a,b]$. Generate $N$ random points and check if these points fall between $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis.

The approximation is achieved by dividing the number of points between the curve and the $x$-axis ($K$) by the total number of points generated ($N$).

This ratio is then multiplied be the total 'area' that the random points have been allowed to fall in. That is, the area of the rectangle with vertices listed clockwise from the top left, $(a,f_{max})$, $(b,f_{max})$, $(b,0)$ and $(a,0)$.

Therefore the approximation is given by $\int^b_af(x)\ \mathrm{d}x\approx\frac{K}{N}\times(b-a)\times f_{max}$.

Hope this is slightly clearer!